# List Of List group Result

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

I have a list of list as follows

```
    var left = (from T in brndT
        join S in brndS
        on T.ID equals S.ID
        into temp
        from S in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new BrandSalesTarget
        {
             ID = T.ID,
             Target = T.Target == null ? 0 : (int)T.Target,
             Sales = S != null ? (int)S.Qty : 0
        }).ToList();
   listOfList.Add(left);
```

Now I want `ID, TotalTarget, TotalSales` 
which means group by list of list with `ID, Sum(target), Sum(sales)`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
var result = 
    from list in listOfList
    from T in list
    group T by T.ID into g
    select new // possibly select new BrandSalesTarget
    {
        ID = g.Key,
        Target = g.Sum(t => t.Target),
        Sales = g.Sum(t => t.Sales)
    };
```

However, it seems the better solution may be to refactor your code so you can derive this result directly, rather than dealing with a `List<List<BrandSalesTarget>>`, but without seeing the full context, it's hard to say how that might look.